# Efficient way to find multiple objects in Arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, equals, contains

I have to check whether an arraylist contains any of the value passed through an object.

Consider an arraylist with values "abc", "jkl","def", "ghi".
And `String check="abc,ghi"`

We have to check whether any of the value in string (abc or ghi) is present in the arraylist and we can stop checking when a match is found.

Traditionally, we can split the `String check` with comma and use `arraylist.contains()` in iteration for each comma separated values.

But this is time consuming. Is there any better way to do this check.

Comment: The best search time you'll get for an `ArrayList` is O(n), unless it's sorted, in which case you'll get O(lg n). Is it possible to use a `HashMap` or `TreeMap`?

Comment: Will hashmap/treemap increase the performance ? Will the comparing logic remains same (comparing with each element) ?

Comment: Any better way with arraylist itself ?

Comment: `HashMap` has O(1) `contains()` complexity. This means that you're *likely* to get a speedup, unless the value you're looking for is consistently one of the first elements you see in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: If you *have* to use `ArrayList`, the best way to speed up a search is to make it sorted. That way, you can use a binary search to find a value in O(lg n) time instead of O(n)

Comment: search on hashmap is based on key, right? In this case, how to set keys and handle it ?

Comment: You can map each string to itself. Unfortunately, you lose the ability to look up an element by its index, but depending on your specific use case this might be acceptable.

Comment: Note that if the input is an ArrayList, then sorting it will take O(n log n) and putting the entries into a HashMap or HashSet will take O(n). You have to take that into consideration, too -- you can't just say that a HashMap lookup is O(1) and be done with it.

Comment: So if using hashmap, is java.util.HashMap.containsKey(Object key) is the method to find the element in iteration or is there any better way ?

Comment: @yshavit Depending on if the `ArrayList` already exists or not, if the elements could be inserted from the beginning the `HashMap` lookup won't have any net penalty at all. There might be a penalty if you had to maintain a sorted `ArrayList` though. Hard to say without more info. But yeah, you're right if switching collection has to be used just for this case.

Comment: @user3580294 Yup, that's why I wrote "if the input is an ArrayList." Incidentally, in this situation a Set is more appropriate than a Map. Maps are for mapping keys to values; Sets are for asking whether a value exists, which is what's needed here.

Comment: You shouldn't need iteration with a `HashMap`, but yes, that's how you find a key. As @yshavit pointed out, you'll have to be careful -- if you *switch* collections just for this, you'll likely incur a penalty that will outweigh any benefits you might gain.

Comment: @yshavit Yep, totally missed that... I need new glasses. Yeah, a `Set` might work better, but if a `Set` is used for this specific case there's still the copying penalty (albeit a smaller one), and a `Set` might not be usable as a replacement for the `ArrayList` in general due to its additional restrictions.

Comment: As an aside: Even **if** one had to use `ArrayList`, there are many additional influencing factors here. For example, a loop like `for (String s : checks) for (String t : list) { ... }` may be noticably slower than `for (String t : list) for (String s : checks) { ... }`, although they both seem to do the same and both have O(n*k) running time. But of course, if it's possible to use a `Set`, then this question does not arise any more.

Comment: @user3580294 In this case, there is no need for switching between collections/Set. The data can be directly stored in map/set and the checking data is in string variable.

Comment: So as per all discussions here, I think `Set` will be the best choice. With set, Mena has posted an answer with `equals()` and Kenster posted with `contains()`. Which method is the best ? `Conatins()` is basically using `equals()` itself, right ?

Comment: @Beauflitz As long as you're sure that your initial data won't have duplicates, then that's perfectly fine. "Best" depends, but I *believe *Kenster's solution would be more efficient as there are fewer operations needed to finish. (`asList()`, `addAll()`, and O(n) iteration + O(1) lookup vs. `asList()`, `addAll()`, `retainAll()`, and `equals()` (not sure of complexity of last two operations but I *think* they are O(n))).

Comment: @user3580294 But in Kenster's solution, the data is residing in `arraylist` itself. we have to go with `Set`, right ?

Comment: @Beauflitz Uh, I think all that matters is that you're performing the comparisons against a `Set` (ideally `HashSet`, where `contains()` is O(1)). You're going to need to iterate through the initial `ArrayList` at some point, whether that is to convert into a `Set` or whether it's in the process of converting the `ArrayList` into a `Set`. So I think his solution essentially skips a step from the other solutions.

Comment: @user3580294 what are the main limitations on using `hashset` over `arraylist` in this case ? The scenario is , we have to check if any one of the string in search string is present in the parent hashset/arraylist.

Comment: Really the only limitation is that if you wanted your original collection to be able to contain duplicates, you no longer have that ability. You have a few options: 1. Store the initial data into a `HashSet`, and then iterate over each of the search strings, checking to see if the initial data contains the search strings. O(n), where n is the number of search strings. Storing the initial data in a `List` and the search strings in a `HashSet` has the same complexity, except n is the number of original strings.

Comment: 2. Store both sets of data into `Lists`. O(n^2). Probably not idea, but you really don't have much of a choice if you require duplicates to be allowed. You can convert both lists into `Sets`, but that's just wasted work over option 1.

Comment: @user3580294 There is no need for duplicate values and switching between collection/set. The parent data can be directly available in `hashset` and search values in a `String` separated by commas. We just have to check if atleast one of the string in search string is present in the `hashset`

Comment: All right, then that sounds like the best solution! O(n) running time, where n is the number of strings you're checking. Not bad.

Comment: So, we have `HashSet<String> data;` and `String check="abc,ghi"; String[] checkArray = check.split(","); for(i){if(data.contains(checkArray[i]))}` . Something like this should work.

Comment: This will have the complexity of O(n). Any option to get O(log n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still O(n), but you could build a set from the search strings and just iterate over the list once:

```
HashSet<String> checks = new HashSet<String>();
checks.addAll(Arrays.asList(check.split(",")));
for (String item : arraylist) {
    if (checks.contains(item)) {
        // Found one
    }
}
```

Comment: As per discussion, `Set` is preferred over `Arraylist`. So, if the data is also available in `Hashset`, can we use equals/contains method to find if any one of the string in checks is present in item ?

Comment: There are efficient ways to tell if two sets have values in common. But in your question, you have two lists--the arraylist and the `split` output. You have to iterate over a list to convert it to a set. Converting both lists to sets just to do a set intersection is more work than necessary.

Comment: Input data can be directly stored in `hashset` rather than storing in `arraylist`.  So, now its a `hashset` of data and search values are present in a `String` separated by commas. Like, `String check="abc,ghi";`

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the `retainAll` method and `Set`s.

**Example**

```
// note an additional "ghi" here
List<String> original = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"abc", "jkl","def", "ghi", "ghi"}));
Set<String> clone = new HashSet<String>(original);
Set<String> control = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"abc","ghi"}));
clone.retainAll(control);
System.out.println(clone.equals(control));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Comment: A little nitpick: as you're calling `retainAll` on `clone` you're actually using `Set#retainAll` rather than `List#retainAll`.

Comment: @Beauflitz I would say so, although there are many factors to consider. One thing for sure is that representing `Collection`s as `String`s in order to compare or manipulate them is definitely not a recommended practice.

Comment: @blalasaadri just saw your comment now - thanks (edited out the ambiguous part).

Comment: As per the discussions, switching between arraylist and set can be avoided and the data can be directly stored in Set.So there is no need for clone. Now, we have 'retainAll()' and then 'equals()', two operations will take time , right ? can we have a solution with one step ?

Comment: Because, we can stop searching when one object in the `Set<String> control` is found in `Set<String> clone`. Either "abc" or "ghi". No need for both to be present in the parent set. So, how can we make this solution better ?

Comment: @Beauflitz if you'd like to change your question to employ `Set`s to start with, you should:  - Change your question (text and code)  - Notify me and all other people who took the time to answer you.  And yes, as `Set`s differ from `List` functionally insofar as they don't allow duplicates, using `Set`s to start with will reduce the number of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform `check` into a regexp and loop only once through the `ArrayList`.

```
String check = "abc,ghi";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + check.replace(',', '|') + ")");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "abc", "jkl", "def", "ghi" });
for (String element : list) {
    if (p.matcher(element).matches()) {
        System.out.println("match: " + element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the best way with arraylist ?

Comment: @Beauflitz It's difficult to say what's "best". I'd imagine that this disguises the additional loops you do, but as I don't know exactly how the `matches()` method works I wouldn't be able to tell you the performance characteristics of this versus your original loop.